# MongoDb C# Keyset pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to implement Keyset pagination with MongoDB c# driver. According to my understanding, the Concept of keyset pagination is you have to pass the last id from the page and find the record greater than that id.

here is my code

```
var filterDef = Builders<Learner>.Filter.Where(predicate);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastRecordId) && isNextPage)
    filterDef &= Builders<Learner>.Filter.Gt(e => e.Id, lastRecordId);
else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastRecordId) && !isNextPage)
    filterDef &= Builders<Learner>.Filter.Lt(e => e.Id, lastRecordId);
var findOption = new FindOptions<Learner>
{
    Sort = Builders<Learner>.Sort.Ascending(t => t.CourseStartDate),
    Limit = 10
};
return (await _collection.FindAsync(filterDef, findOption)).ToList();
```

The above code works fine for the next pages. I mean users keep clicking on the next page and the record will show up.. But the issue when the user clicks on the previous page the server sends the first 10 records from DB.

For example, User visits 4th page of the records and as soon as he clicks the previous it sends back the user's very first 10 records rather than the middle 10 records.

How to handle this situation?

Comment: How do you know which button is clicked next or previous? Also what is `isNextPage`?

Comment: I have two buttons on my UI Next and previous. When the user clicks the Next button I get the last record id and send it to the server and then filter the record which is greater than that id.

Comment: when the user clicks the previous button I set the isNextPage variable to false. it means now the user is requested for the previous page record. So I grab the id of the first record on that current page and send it to the server then the server filter the record which must be less then the passed id.

Comment: But on previous after comparing less than it gives me first 10 records. Its kind of like resetting

Comment: `Builders<Learner>.Sort.Ascending` may be a reason of your problem. in case of previous use `Sort.Decendeing`